# MariaDB index for queries of a subset of column1 and range of column2

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-indexes

I have this query:

`SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 IN (*small set of values*) AND column3 > number`

My table has 3 columns, primary key is (column1, column2).

So I was looking into composite indexes but its not very clear to me in what order should the columns in the index be (column2, column3) or (column3, column2) since there isnt much info of how exactly will the BTree for this composite index be built (at least I couldnt understand).

So, how is the tree built and will it help me more than creating and index only for column2 for example?

Bonus question: I saw something about "covering" index which seems to work for me here, but seeing as there are no "free meals", what is the implications of this? Less of the index fits into memory? Does MariaDB even store the index in memory?

Answer (score 1):

(I assume you are using InnoDB.)

- `INDEX(col2, ...)` will be better if the `IN` is more selective than the `>`.
- `INDEX(col3, ...)` will be better if the `>` is more selective.
- InnoDB always puts the `PRIMARY KEY` column(s) onto the end of each secondary index.  Hence, `INDEX(col2, col3)` is very much like `INDEX(col2, col3, col1)`, which is "covering".  Ditto for `(col3, col2)`.
- When expecting the PK to be added, I explicitly add it -- this is a clue to other users (and myself) that I was striving for 'covering' or whatever.
- The Optimizer (cf "MRR") *may* be able to leapfrog through `IN` values, so...

I recommend specifically:

```
INDEX(col2,        -- hoping to leapfrog
      col3,        -- assuming the leapfrogging works
      col1)        -- covering
```

It *may* be better to change to `PRIMARY KEY(col2, col1)` and *not* have the extra index.  This *assumes* that you did not have `col1` first in the PK to benefit some other query/queries.

How is a composite index done in a BTree?  Think of concatenating the columns (col1, col2) together to make a single key.  (The details may be messier, but thinking of it this way "works".)

Further note:  The Data is a BTree of the data, ordered according to the PK.  A secondary index is a BTree of the columns in the secondary index, plus PK, with nothing extra in the leaf nodes.

MySQL and MariaDB store all indexes on disk (see above), then cache the 16KB blocks in the "buffer_pool", which is in RAM.  After a system has run for a while, the index blocks *tend* to be in that cache; the data blocks may or may not.

If you are only looking at, say, "new" rows in a large, time-oriented, table, then the blocks indexed by a date or `AUTO_INCREMENT` id will tend to be in ram, while the "older" rows stay on disk.

That's the beauty of "caching" -- you come closer to a "free meal" than by clumsier techniques.  Such as...  "I will load all of my indexes into RAM."  But what if I am only using the 'newer' parts of it; that will crowd out other uses of RAM.  "I will lock this table in RAM."  Again, this steals from other uses of RAM that might be more effective.